# Where can I find Windows 3.11 drivers for my Video Blaster capture card?

Tags: driver

Where can I find a Windows 3.11 driver for a Creative Technologies CT6042 Video Blaster card? I need it to recover a piece of 90s era test equipment.

Answer (score 3):

[VOGONS](http://vogonsdrivers.com/) has a library of old DOS and early Windows drivers.  They have the drivers for the CT6080. I can't tell if this is compatible or not.

Also [oldskool.org](ftp://ftp.oldskool.org/pub/drivers/Creative/) has an FTP repository that includes Video Blaster drivers (no model# I can see)

Comment: The oldskool FTP does have a VideoBlaster directory and the README explicitly includes windows 3.1. I will try it when I get the chance.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can download them [from the MCbx Old Computer Collection](https://oldcomputer.info/pc/skladaki/k6-iii/), for Windows 9x; scroll to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you very much. In this case however the drivers do not seem to be compatible with Win 3.11, which I now realized I did not specify in the original question. Downloading the drivers did help me improve my search queries as I found that the card was also identified as SE100.

Comment: You can [edit your question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/posts/21922/edit) to clarify your requirements. Did you find what you were looking for by looking for SE100 drivers?

Comment: A lot more hits, but still no luck.